# Mocked CloseableHttpClient is sending real POST request

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have an unit test for for Spring Boot class which sends a file to URL with POST request when I run the test it is sending actual request to the real url. I think the CloseableHttpClient is not getting mocked.

```
class FileSenderTest {
    @InjectMocks
    FileSender fileSender;
    
    @Mock
    UrlConfig urlConfig;
    
    @Mock
    InetAddress inetAddress;

    @Mock
    SSLContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SSLContextFactory();

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
    }
   
    @Test
    public void postData() throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("/someUrl");
        urlConfig.setURL(url);
        urlConfig.setPassword("somePassword123");
        fileSender = new FileSender(urlConfig);

        URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.json");
        File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
        String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        
        HttpPost httpPost = mock(HttpPost.class);
        StatusLine statusLine = mock(StatusLine.class);
        CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
        CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);

        when(statusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);
        when(closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLine);
        when(closeable.HttpClient.execute(httpPost)).thenReturn(closeableHttpResponse);

        int response = fileSender.sendFile(filePath);

        Assertions.assertEquals(200, response);
    }

}
```

And here is the class to test:

```
@Service 
public class FileSender {
    private final UrlConfig urlConfig;
    SSLContext sslContext;
    
    @Autowired
    public FileSender(UrlConfig urlConfig) {
        this.urlConfig = urlConfig;
    }

    public int sendFile(String targetFileName) throws IOException {
        Path tracesPath = Paths.get(targetFileName);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(this.UrlConfig.getURL().toString());
        httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();        
        builder.addBinary("file", new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(tracesPath)), ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, targetFileName);

        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
        httpPost.setEntity(multipart);
        
        sslContext = this.UrlConfig.getSSLContext();
        sslContext = SSLContextFactory.create().this.urlConfig.setSSLContext(sslContext);

       try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()setSSLContext(sslContext).build);
           CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)) {
               return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
               log.error(e);
        }
        return 500;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to solve the issue refactoring only the test.

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems here:

You are using `@InjectMocks` (used to inject mocks to the constructor of the test subject, in your service this one only takes one argument, so the rest are not injected). At the same time you are adding it manually in the test method `fileSender = new FileSender(urlConfig);` this is redundant (I would probably recommend you to delete the annotation and use the one inside of the test method, as you are setting `urlConfig` there).

As said, you are not injecting any of the following mocks because `FileSender` constructor only takes `urlConfig` as a parameter. If you want to instantiate `FileSender` with the mocks that you are declaring you need to create an extra constructor that takes them as a parameter.

```
@Mock SSLContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SSLContextFactory();
@Mock InetAddress inetAddress;
HttpPost httpPost = mock(HttpPost.class);
StatusLine statusLine = mock(StatusLine.class);
CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
```

You also have many static calls in the test subject, which are difficult to mock as they are tightly coupled to their respective classes. You may need to figure out what to do specifically with each one of those calls.

Comment: Thanks for the explaining the problem. Do you have any suggestions how to solve the problem with injecting?

Comment: Yes, as said, you need to override the constructor in the test subject class in order to be able to inject your mocks